# using GtkAlignment for horizontal alignment

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I am new to GTK+ world and trying to learn it from Foundations of GTK+ Development.

Mean while I am getting some problem in using GtkAlignment widget, as in the code below.

Even if I change the value of either one of the below I am not getting the Ok and calcel button getting aligned to right.

```
GtkWidget* halign = gtk_alignment_new(0, 0, 0, 0);
GtkWidget* halign = gtk_alignment_new(0, 1, 0, 0);
```

I think I'm missing something, but not getting exactly

Note: I am using GTK+3 on windows 7

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

```
GtkWidget* window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Gtk Alignment Sample");
gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 5);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(window, 250, 400);
g_signal_connect(window, "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);


GtkWidget* ok_button = gtk_button_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_OK);
GtkWidget* cancel_button = gtk_button_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_CANCEL);

GtkWidget* hbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), ok_button,     FALSE, FALSE, 0);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), cancel_button, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

GtkWidget* halign = gtk_alignment_new(0, 0, 0, 0);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(halign), hbox);

GtkWidget* vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), halign, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

GtkWidget* valign = gtk_alignment_new(0, 1, 0, 0);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(valign), vbox);

gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), valign);
gtk_widget_show_all(window);

gtk_main();
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.10/GtkAlignment):

> Note that the desired effect can in most cases be achieved by using
>   the "halign", "valign" and "margin" properties on the child widget, so
>   GtkAlignment should not be used in new code.

Try to just use

```
gtk_widget_set_alignment (button_ok, GTK_ALIGN_END);
gtk_widget_set_alignment (button_cancel, GTK_ALIGN_END);
//or
gtk_widget_set_alignment (hbox, GTK_ALIGN_END);
```

and remove all alignment widgets

Comment: Since I'm leaning GtkAlignment widget, that why I wanted to know why this is not working. But yes there are lots of alternative for this.